# Email Sending issue in PHP

Tags: php, email, sendmail.exe

I am trying to send an Email through php and before I present the problem, the things I did are---

1. I have Xampp and I have Mercury Turned on, I have made 2 local users.
2. I have Thunderbird to receive the email and I have it all set up. That is I can send email from one local user to another without any problem.
3. Now my email php code is simple

`mail('revan@localhost','Hello!','Hello, This is a test!','FROM:sunny@localhost') or die("Email sending failed");


?>`

4)Now in my php.ini  the mail function looks like---

```
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP =localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = sunny@localhost

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path = “\”C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\” -t”

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

Now the problem is...I get no error message but I am receiving no emails.

The Mercury log

```
T 20130114 003213 50f35170 Connection from 127.0.0.1
T 20130114 003213 50f35170 EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org
T 20130114 003213 50f35170 QUIT
T 20130114 003213 50f35170 Connection closed with 127.0.0.1, 0 sec. elapsed.
T 20130114 003213 50f35171 Connection from 127.0.0.1
T 20130114 003213 50f35171 EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org
T 20130114 003213 50f35171 QUIT
T 20130114 003213 50f35171 Connection closed with 127.0.0.1, 0 sec. elapsed.
T 20130114 003912 50f35393 Connection from 127.0.0.1
T 20130114 003912 50f35393 EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org
T 20130114 003912 50f35393 QUIT
T 20130114 003912 50f35393 Connection closed with 127.0.0.1, 0 sec. elapsed.
T 20130114 003912 50f35394 Connection from 127.0.0.1
T 20130114 003912 50f35394 EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org
T 20130114 003912 50f35394 QUIT
T 20130114 003912 50f35394 Connection closed with 127.0.0.1, 0 sec. elapsed.
T 20130114 003949 50f35395 Connection from 127.0.0.1
T 20130114 003949 50f35396 Connection from 127.0.0.1
T 20130114 003949 50f35395 EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org
T 20130114 003949 50f35395 QUIT
T 20130114 003949 50f35395 Connection closed with 127.0.0.1, 0 sec. elapsed.
T 20130114 003949 50f35396 EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org
T 20130114 003949 50f35396 QUIT
T 20130114 003949 50f35396 Connection closed with 127.0.0.1, 0 sec. elapsed.
T 20130114 004614 50f35397 Connection from 127.0.0.1
T 20130114 004614 50f35397 EHLO [127.0.0.1]
T 20130114 004614 50f35397 MAIL FROM:<sunny@localhost> SIZE=359
T 20130114 004614 50f35397 RCPT TO:<revan@locahost>
T 20130114 004614 50f35397 RSET
T 20130114 004614 50f35397 RSET
T 20130114 004615 50f35397 MAIL FROM:<sunny@localhost> SIZE=359
T 20130114 004615 50f35397 RCPT TO:<revan@locahost>
T 20130114 004615 50f35397 DATA
T 20130114 004615 50f35397 DATA - 12 lines, 361 bytes.
T 20130114 004615 50f35397 QUIT
T 20130114 004615 50f35397 Connection closed with 127.0.0.1, 1 sec. elapsed.
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 Connection from 127.0.0.1
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 EHLO [127.0.0.1]
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 MAIL FROM:<sunny@localhost> SIZE=367
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 RCPT TO:<revan@localhost>
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 RSET
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 RSET
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 MAIL FROM:<sunny@localhost> SIZE=367
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 RCPT TO:<revan@localhost>
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 DATA
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 DATA - 12 lines, 369 bytes.
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 QUIT
T 20130114 004713 50f35398 Connection closed with 127.0.0.1, 0 sec. elapsed.
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 Connection from 127.0.0.1
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 EHLO [127.0.0.1]
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 MAIL FROM:<revan@localhost> SIZE=379
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 RCPT TO:<sunny@localhost>
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 RSET
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 RSET
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 MAIL FROM:<revan@localhost> SIZE=379
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 RCPT TO:<sunny@localhost>
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 DATA
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 DATA - 12 lines, 381 bytes.
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 QUIT
T 20130114 004750 50f35399 Connection closed with 127.0.0.1, 0 sec. elapsed.
```

Comment: Wow that formatting makes me feel dizzy

Comment: can you turn on mail log ? also, make sure you have error reporting set to E_ALL

Comment: What do you mean by "error reporting set to  E_ALL" ?, sorry I am very new with these things And there is the mercury log.

Comment: why did you make 2 local users? just for sending mails?

Comment: To Send a mail from one to another....?or you dont need it?

Comment: ok Fine but I am still not getting the mail.

Comment: mind `RCPT TO:<revan@locahost>` you miss letter "L" in localhost

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$to      = 'your_other_email@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: sunny@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: sunny@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

see [more](http://www.nbilyk.com/sending-mail-from-localhost)

i would avoid sending from localhost to localhost ..

Comment: I tried that, I used my Gmail account as 'sunny@example.com' and "sunny@localhost" as 'your_other_email@example.com' But its not working still.

Comment: Go to your php.ini file and change SMTP = localhost to SMTP = aspmx.l.google.com and uncomment sendmail_from and put in your sending gmail address.  - did this?